# place Speech recognition void inside Fragment and then call from MainActivity app crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, speech-recognition

i have one MainActivity and one Fragment, the Fragment include promptSpeechInput() and onActivityResult() voids. my plan is to place those speech to text recognition code into the fragment then call them with function fro the MainActivity, i did it and got no error when i run it but when i execute the void in the app. It crashes and i dont know why, please help.

MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentSideButton.Headline {

    Button btn;
    Speech speech = new Speech(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOnMic();
            }
        });
   }

   @Override
    public void turnOnMic() {
        speech.promptSpeechInput();
    }
}
```

Speech Fragment code:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Speech extends Fragment{
    Context context;

    public Speech(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void promptSpeechInput(){
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"say something");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException a){
            Toast.makeText(context,"sorry your device does not support speech to text ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request_code,int result_code,Intent i){
        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);

        switch (request_code)
        {
            case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                //resultText.setText(result.get(0));
                Toast.makeText(context,result.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize classes that take a Context object from your Activity like that. The Context of your Activity is only usable once `onCreate()` is called.

Also, Fragments already have a reference to a Context once they're attached to your Activity. Just use `getContext()` (Marshmallow+) or `getActivity()`.

Remove your custom constructor, remove the global `context` variable and use `getContext()` or `getActivity()` instead.

You also need to actually add your Fragment to your Activity. I honestly don't really understand why you're using a Fragment.

EDIT:

If you just want a helper class, don't use a Fragment. Fragments are for adding new UI elements to your Activity, not for reducing boilerplate code.

However, the way you're using this, you can't use a helper class either, and shouldn't. Just keep this code in your Activity. If you need to use it in multiple Activities, create a "base" Activity with this logic built in and then extend that class in your other Activities.

Note: Do **NOT** register the base Activity in your Manifest.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentSideButton.Headline {
    @Override
    public void turnOnMic() {
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"say something");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException a){
            Toast.makeText(context,"sorry your device does not support speech to text ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request_code,int result_code,Intent i){
        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);

        switch (request_code)
        {
            case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                //resultText.setText(result.get(0));
                Toast.makeText(context,result.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can extend it:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOnMic();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think the problem is the context, i only use context to show a string in the app (it was only used for TOAST.maketext), i delete it and re-run it. and it still crash

Comment: Well you've got plenty of other issues too. You haven't attached the Fragment to your Activity. `startActivityForResult()` in the Fragment is just a proxy to call the parent Activity's `startActivityForResult()`. Why are you using a Fragment?

Comment: i am using because i want to make MainActivity to be less crowded with code. and so i can re use the same code in case i want to add mic in another activity. btw what do you mean by attached Fragment to the activity? how do i do that?

Comment: Don't use a Fragment. This isn't what they're for. I'll update my answer.

Comment: what should i put on  @Override
    public void turnOnMic() {
        
    } because speech.promptSpeechInput(); is the same thing

Comment: @javaperson look at my code. I just copied what you had in the Speech class over.

Comment: nvm, sorry i didnt saw that